# What happens when a microSD card is worn out by Pi?

Tags: storage

> "Many have experienced their micro SD card becoming corrupted or flat out dying over time when used on the Pi." -- Some person on Reddit.

I have read that microSD card is not designed to be a system disk, and it has a fixed number of write times. But probably not all cells (I mean, section, portion, etc of the storage) will be worn out at once.  If some cells worn out, does the microSD card still work with the remaining cells? For example, if it is a 64GB card and 10% of cells worn out, 58GB (64*0.9) is still usable? If so, does the Pi OS operate as if the card is a 58GB card and prevents writing more than 58GB? Or there is no such thing and the write operation simply fails if I try to write more than 58GB?

Or does the whole microSD card become unusable?

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally an SD card fails safe.

By that it goes into a read only mode so you can get the data off BUT not corrupt any new data being written to it.  This may not help as it could lead to corrupt file table entries or duff records / index in databases.

Each card manufacturer has a tolerance of spare memory that extends the life BUT it's not possible to tell when this is used up so failures are normally catastrophic and data is lost when the writes fail.

Type A1 and A2 cards are the first steps from manufacturers to allow for applications BUT they still state operating systems should not be used and some warranties specifically exclude this use from failure cover.